# CloudFormation for DynamoDB: "Encountered unsupported property AttributeType"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

Deployment of DynamoDB stack rollbacks with error:

> CREATE_FAILED Encountered unsupported property AttributeType

I tried various modifications of attributes configuration, used quotes, also checked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56140503/unsupported-property-attributetype-in-cloudformation-dynamo-db-deployment).

My template:

```
Resources:
checkpointsTable:
Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
Properties: 
  AttributeDefinitions:
    - AttributeName: sf_instance_table_key
      AttributeType: S
  BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
  KeySchema: 
    - AttributeName: sf_instance_table_key
      AttributeType: HASH
  TableName: !Ref tableName
  Tags: 
    - Key: "Division"
      Value: !Ref division
```

Not many lines here, but cannot figure it out. Thanks for help!

Comment: It should be `KeyType`, not `AttributeType` in [KeySchema](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-keyschema.html).

Comment: @gshpychka of course I read, but didn't notice this small difference between Attributes and Keys definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
Resources:
checkpointsTable:
Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
Properties: 
  AttributeDefinitions:
    - AttributeName: sf_instance_table_key
      AttributeType: S
  BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
  KeySchema: 
    - AttributeName: sf_instance_table_key
      KeyType: HASH
  TableName: !Ref tableName
  Tags: 
    - Key: "Division"
      Value: !Ref division
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved issue.